# What causes Joker to become a ghost?

Tags: batman-arkham-city

Randomly, Joker, in the Joker's Carnival DLC combat challenge stage, will become unhittable. He'll still move as though he is fighting, but he'll never attack, he won't be able to be targeted, and I don't think he can be hit by anything. I think it happened once after I did a beatdown finisher on him. What causes it to happen?

Update: Here's footage of it happening:

Comment: I m inclined to think it is a bug where the Joker's model isn't set to "ko", but is still considered "ko".

Comment: Just curious, does using the Stun move on him have no effect either?

Comment: @Guy Untouchable.

Answer (score 1):

In Riddler's Challenges, the final level of a challenge is forcibly with 2 modifiers: time limit and random unhittability.

Maybe that DLC uses the same modifiers.